# SQL to return product and product dependencies

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table (`product`) which lists all products. I have another table (`product_buddy`) that is a mapping of dependencies.

I've setup a simple [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82a7df/4)

In the fiddle, there are 3 products: foo, bar, baz. There is also a row in `product_buddy` where baz is a dependency of foo. So if I `SELECT` foo, I want it to also return baz. But if I `SELECT` bar, it has no dependency so it should just return bar. Same with baz, it doesn't have a dependency so it should just return itself. Only foo should return two rows in this fiddle.

A join will simply join it into a single row which isn't what I want, I want two rows with each product's code and name fields. When I say two rows, if I `SELECT` foo, it should return both the foo row and baz row because of the dependency:

```
# SQL without missing join/binding of dependency:
SELECT code,name FROM product WHERE product.code = "foo";

| code | name        |
|------|-------------|
| foo  | Foo Product |
| baz  | Baz Product |
```

The result is the same if I did this:

```
SELECT code,name FROM product WHERE product.code IN ("foo", "baz");
```

but I don't know the dependency ahead of time. I need the SQL to figure out the dependency. I'm ok with editing the `product_buddy` table, the `product` table needs to stay the same.

Comment: Can you post your desired result?

Comment: Even when SqlFiddle is recomend to help describe the question, you should try to provide most of the info here in case outside link are lost.

Comment: Added an example response, when I retrieve the foo product, I need it to return both foo and baz rows because of the dependency defined in the `product_buddy` table.

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82a7df/13)

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM product p
WHERE p.code = "foo" 

UNION

SELECT
    p.*
FROM product_buddy b           
INNER JOIN product p
   on b.buddy_code = p.code
WHERE b.product_code = "foo"
```

Result

```
id  code    name
1   foo     Foo Product
3   baz     Baz Product
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH dep (dependencies) AS 
    (SELECT buddy_code 
     FROM product_buddy
     WHERE product_code = code_searched)
SELECT code, name
FROM product
WHERE code in dep.dependencies OR code = code_searched
```

Edit:

Apparently MySQL doesn't support WITH clause :S

```
select code, name
from product
where product.code = "foo" 
    OR product.code IN (SELECT buddy_code 
                        FROM product_buddy
                        WHERE product_buddy.product_code = "foo")
```

Comment: I try your code in the fiddle and doesnt work.:( i replace both `code_searched` for "foo"

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't try it, fiddle just not working for me

Comment: Please try check it later and leave me a message if you make it work. Ty.

Comment: Ohh yes Mysql is silly about that. But I will test your aproach on postgres or MSSQL, That line `IN dep.dependencies` looks very interesting.